# Use master thesis or master's thesis

Tags: possessives

Is this sentence correct?

> Master thesis to obtain the degree Master of Science

I am really not sure about the *'s* here.

Comment: You can search a corpus such as COCA: [*master thesis*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31034805) - [*master's thesis*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31034804)

Comment: Seems redundant to me. If you name the degree, the purpose of the thesis is already clear.

Comment: At EL&U: *[Is there an apostrophe in a master's degree?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638)*

Comment: For a start, it's not a sentence, just a fragment of one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[As suggested by snailplane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/use-master-thesis-or-masters-thesis#comment46039_24377), corpus searches are a good way to get a handle on which one is preferred.

- [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=master%20thesis,master%27s%20thesis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,master%20thesis;,c0;.t1;,master%20%27s%20thesis;,c0) prefers *master's thesis* by a roughly six to one margin at the year 2000.
- The Corpus of Contemporary American English prefers *master's thesis* ([212](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31034804) to [6](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31034805)).
- [The Corpus of Global Web Based English](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) prefers *master's thesis* (384 to 82). Sorry, no direct query links here, since the site uses iframes and I'm too lazy to dig the URLs out. Search *master 's thesis* (note the space before the apostrophe) and *master thesis*. This one is a nice corpus because it breaks usages up by country.
- [The Time Magazine Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/time/) prefers *master's thesis* 23 to 0 (same search guidelines as above).

I also searched many an exclusively British corpus, but without yielding any meaningful results.

[The relevant ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/is-there-an-apostrophe-in-a-masters-degree) that [choster linked](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/use-master-thesis-or-masters-thesis#comment46080_24377) discusses *master's degree*, which has the same form as *master's thesis*. The question is about apostrophe usage, but note that nobody suggested it should be *master degree*.

Grammatically speaking, *master's thesis* unequivocally means a *thesis of a master*. *Master thesis* can be read the same way, but also as *primary, principle or main thesis*.

Stick with *master's thesis*.

Comment: It seems like every single chair of my (German) university's CS department uses _Master thesis_ and it's making me question my sanity -- thanks for this.